# A noun for the act of misinterpreting a word

Tags: nouns, terminology

When someone says a word that is superficially similar to, but means something different from, what they really mean, we call it a malapropism. I'm looking for the counterpart to this—a word for the act of wrongly *interpreting* a correctly spoken or written word.

When the problem is purely acoustic, as in this example:

> OLD GEEZER #1:  It's windy today!
>
> OLD GEEZER #2:  No, it's Thursday.
>
> OLD GEEZER #3:  Me too! Let's get a drink.

then we call it a [Mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) (thank you [KJO](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/477964/61956) for the term) but I'm looking for a word that covers failures of the hearer's vocabulary (just as a malapropism is a failure of the speaker's vocabulary).

One example might be from Stanley Holloway's 1931 monologue "The Recumbent Posture" in which the instructions on Albert's bottle of medicine dictate that it is to be taken "in a recumbent posture" leading his parents to scour the town in search of such an object.

Of course, sometimes it can be done deliberately:

> MRS FUSSEY: Joan may think you're a gentleman but personally I've got sore misgivings.
>
> SID BOGGLE: You ought to put some talcum powder on them.
>
> (Carry on Camping, 1969)

Comment: Mrs. Piggle Wiggle called it "Thought-You-Saiditis" or "Thought-You-Saiding". The cure is magic hearing powder, sprinkled in the ears.

Comment: Or thoughtisaurus puddy-tat?

Answer (score 4):

It could be classified as

**A mondegreen** /ˈmɒndɪɡriːn/ is a mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as a result of near-homophony, in a way that gives it a new meaning

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen

related to the second example is a [Syntactic ambiguity, also called amphiboly or amphibology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity) so one could call it a "jocular amphiboly" such as

> "The peasants are revolting"
>   "They are aren't they"

which is also related to an [Egg corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) and [Mumpsimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumpsimus)

Answer (score 2):

**misconstrual**

Meaning as a verb (*misconstrue)*

> Interpret (a person's words or actions) wrongly.

Definitions from Oxford Dictionaries

> *Did I misconstrue your thoughts when you looked at me in the Queen's
>    boudoir?*

From  *Cinq Mars, Complete*

*Alfred de Vigny*

[***misconstrue***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misconstrue][1])

[***misconstrual***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misconstruable)

**Definitions from Oxford Dictionaries**